# Android Studio Yahoo Finance Fragment - What's wrong here?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, yahoo-finance

I am trying to simply show the prices of the S&P and NASDAQ indices. For some reason my application keeps crashing though. The code works in Eclipse just not in Android Studio. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my fragment:

```
package com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import yahoofinance.Stock;
    import yahoofinance.YahooFinance;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public static String spPriceS;
    public static String spPercentS;
    public static String nasdaqPriceS;
    public static String nasdaqPercentS;

    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        yahoofinance.Stock stockOne = YahooFinance.get("^GSPC");
        BigDecimal spPriceBD = stockOne.getQuote().getPrice();
        HomeFragment.spPriceS = spPriceBD.toString();
        BigDecimal spPercentBD = stockOne.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
        HomeFragment.spPercentS = spPercentBD.toString();

        yahoofinance.Stock stockTwo = YahooFinance.get("^IXIC");
        BigDecimal nasdaqPriceBD = stockTwo.getQuote().getPrice();
        HomeFragment.nasdaqPriceS = nasdaqPriceBD.toString();
        BigDecimal nasdaqPercentBD = stockTwo.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
        HomeFragment.nasdaqPercentS = nasdaqPercentBD.toString();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        TextView spPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_price);
        spPrice.setText(spPriceS);
        TextView spPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_percent);
        spPercent.setText(spPercentS);

        TextView nasdaqPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nasdaq_price);
        nasdaqPrice.setText(nasdaqPriceS);
        TextView nasdaqPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nasdaq_percent);
        nasdaqPercent.setText(nasdaqPercentS);

    }

}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
04-13 20:04:39.144: D/AndroidRuntime(2539): Shutting down VM
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539): Process: com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal, PID: 2539
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.NavDrawer}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest.getResult(QuotesRequest.java:83)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:332)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:76)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:61)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:38)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-13 20:04:39.144: E/AndroidRuntime(2539):     ... 10 more
04-13 20:04:39.152: W/ActivityManager(1233):   Force finishing activity com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.NavDrawer
04-13 20:04:39.487: I/Choreographer(1233): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 20:04:39.494: E/gralloc_goldfish(932): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 576 x 576, usage 333
04-13 20:04:39.494: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(932): alloc(576, 576, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
04-13 20:04:39.494: E/(932): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=576, h=576) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
04-13 20:04:39.496: E/BufferQueueProducer(1233): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
04-13 20:04:39.497: W/WindowManager(1233): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (1080x1920) to layer 21015
04-13 20:04:39.498: E/ActivityManager(1233): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
04-13 20:04:39.506: D/Atlas(1233): Validating map...
04-13 20:04:39.564: I/OpenGLRenderer(1233): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-13 20:04:39.601: W/EGL_emulation(1233): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-13 20:04:39.601: W/OpenGLRenderer(1233): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb0a12e20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-13 20:04:42.403: D/TaskPersister(1233): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=398_task.xml
04-13 20:04:43.226: I/Choreographer(1233): Skipped 214 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 20:04:43.338: W/ActivityManager(1233): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{8853baa u0 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/.NavDrawer t399 f}
04-13 20:04:43.804: W/EGL_emulation(1536): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-13 20:04:43.805: W/OpenGLRenderer(1536): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa65402c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-13 20:04:44.989: I/Process(2539): Sending signal. PID: 2539 SIG: 9
04-13 20:04:44.996: W/AudioTrack(1233): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-13 20:04:45.094: W/InputDispatcher(1233): channel '9e101c6 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-13 20:04:45.095: E/InputDispatcher(1233): channel '9e101c6 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-13 20:04:45.137: I/ActivityManager(1233): Process com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal (pid 2539) has died
04-13 20:04:45.205: I/WindowState(1233): WIN DEATH: Window{9e101c6 u0 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.LoginActivity}
04-13 20:04:45.205: W/InputDispatcher(1233): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '9e101c6 com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal/com.capstone.hammond.wallstreetfantasyleaguefinal.LoginActivity (server)'
04-13 20:04:47.483: W/SurfaceFlinger(932): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
04-13 20:04:47.640: W/InputMethodManagerService(1233): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2539 uid 10059
04-13 20:04:47.745: W/OpenGLRenderer(1536): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-13 20:04:47.746: W/OpenGLRenderer(1536): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-13 20:04:47.746: W/OpenGLRenderer(1536): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
04-13 20:04:48.744: D/TaskPersister(1233): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=399_task.xml
04-13 20:05:21.633: I/ActivityManager(1233): Killing 1876:com.android.music/u0a36 (adj 15): empty #17
04-13 20:05:21.684: W/libprocessgroup(1233): failed to open /acct/uid_10036/pid_1876/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
04-13 20:11:04.911: I/art(1502): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15182(816KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 1706KB/2MB, paused 5.802ms total 50.040ms
```

Comment: The stacktrace you have posted tells you exactly why your application is crashing. Have you tried reading it?

Comment: @Mike Hammond you can't run a process that blocks your main thread. It needs to be moved to a background thread. Have a look at AsyncTask